# How to get all the props that a parent component has inside a child component In vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How to get all the props like $store, $parent, $root everything that a parent component has inside a child component?

So I'm creating a parent component and a child.
However I don't have anything to render within the child. So I'm creating a renderless child component.

However I'm programatically inserting new html elements via child component

following piece of code is the parent component where I mount the child component.

This is the method I found online.

This is working fine. But I'm not getting the props like `this.$store` , `this.$parent` and all (which are automatically available inside the parent component) in the child component.

```
import { Child } from "./components/child";

export default {
  name: "parent",
  components: {},
  props: [],
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {},
  created() {
    new Child().$mount();
  },
  mounted() {},
  methods: {},
};
```

This is the child component.

```
import Vue from "vue";

const CHILD = {
  name: "child",
  components: {},
  props: [],
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  render() {
    return;
  },
  computed: {},
  created() {},
  mounted() {},
  methods: {},
};

export const Child = Vue.extend(CHILD);
```

So the basic idea is to create child component classes having all the options like `$store` `$el` and all (everything vue provides).... but instead of instantiating it inside the template I want to instantiate them in the parent component like this: `new Child({...props})`.

So is that possible. I'm doing this because my child components are renderless.  (But within the child components I'm creating Dom elements..., & the reason I want to extend all the functionalities provided by vue is because in that way I don't want to write my own store, my own event emitter, my own prop binder.... everything will be automatically available...)

**KEY TAKEAWAY** is that I want to create Child components manually like by calling `new Child()` rather than registering them as components inside the parent as `components: {'app-child': Child}` and instantiating them inside the parent template ... Along with that I want every functionalities provided by vue inside the child component.. something like extending vue..

Also How can I listen to events from the child created as above ...

something like this.

```
// child 


created() {
this.$emit('event')
}




//parent 

mounted() {
this.child.$on('event', console.log)

}
```

sources:

https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/

https://css-tricks.com/building-renderless-vue-components/

Comment: No. I mean I don't want it in the vue way to instantiate components... I want to do. it manually due to some reasons...

Comment: Of course I don't know your reasons but maybe you should create new question and describe it there (what are you trying to solve). `new Child().$mount()` does not create any *child* component. Its just completely new and independent Vue instance on the page. Also *child components are renderless. (But within the child components I'm creating Dom elements* ...that's so wrong. Why are you creating "renderless" components and then manually create DOM elements. Doesn't make sense at all. Well you have my advice above, take it or leave it...

Comment: Well, you should if you want it to work correctly. `Child` isn't supposed to be called manually. A way that Vue provides is `new Vue(...)`. It's likely that you have XY problem that needs to be solved in another way.

Comment: But on that link provided, it is done manually... But even if I do it in the way ```new Vue(...)``` how will I mount / register chid inside the parent. since this child doesn't have a template nor an html tag that represents the child... how can I mount the child...

Comment: The child will have to be created and mounted manually as shown above. since it doesn't have any html tag like this ```<app-child></app-child>```.

I wanna do it this way ```new Child()``` because I don't have anything to do with the template... so the event emission and props passing will have to be done through this instance of child...